# How to add a sum column considering a pattern in name column if a condition is TRUE and substract it from the original column

Tags: r, sum, contains

I have this:

```
transaction_id <- c(17,95,27,16,8)
r1<- c(84,28,18,51,98)
r1_added<- c(66,15,56,22,74)
r2<-c(50,58,52,90,97)
r2_added <-c(31,95,28,80,9)
r3<-c(20,91,61,87,11)
r3_added <-c(68,38,99,43,49)
condition <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
m <- as.data.frame(cbind(idc,transaction_id,r1,r1_added,r2,r2_added,r3,r3_added,condition))
```

| idc | transaction_id | r1 | r1_added | r2 | r2_added | r3 | r3_added | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 84 | 66 | 50 | 31 | 20 | 68 | 0 |
| 2 | 95 | 28 | 15 | 58 | 95 | 91 | 38 | 1 |
| 3 | 27 | 18 | 56 | 52 | 28 | 61 | 99 | 0 |
| 4 | 16 | 51 | 22 | 90 | 80 | 87 | 43 | 1 |
| 5 | 8 | 98 | 74 | 97 | 9 | 11 | 49 | 0 |

I need the sum of all values of columns names that ends with "added" in a new column but substract or assign 0 to those columns value

I need this: rows with condition 1 has to sum in "sum_added" but 0 in the columns that sum

| idc | transaction_id | r1 | r1_added | r2 | r2_added | r3 | r3_added | condition | sum_added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 84 | 66 | 50 | 31 | 20 | 68 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 95 | 28 | 0 | 58 | 0 | 91 | 0 | 1 | 148 |
| 3 | 27 | 18 | 56 | 52 | 28 | 61 | 99 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 16 | 51 | 0 | 90 | 0 | 87 | 0 | 1 | 145 |
| 5 | 8 | 98 | 74 | 97 | 9 | 11 | 49 | 0 | 0 |

I was trying with dyplyr:

```
m%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(sum_added=ifelse(condition==1,sum(c_across(contains("_added"))),0))
```

but i don't know how to assign 0 to columns that sum, considering i have a lot of columns "added" not only 3 of this example

I need clarify,  i need for example r1_added =0 , r2_added=0,,, and so on,updating values.

Comment: You can multiply the result by column "condition" in a mutate step

Comment: but i need for example r1_added =0 , r2_added=0,,, and so on.... may be i didnt clarify that, maybe can use with mutate but updating the r[n]_added values, somethink like... mutate(contains("_added")=0) but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select the columns that `ends_with` "_added" with `across` (or `pick`), get the row wise sum (`rowSums`), and multiply with `condition` (values that are 0 in condition will return 0 and those will 1 return the sum value), then loop `across` the `_added` and multiply with the negated (`!`) condition to modify the values in `_added` to 0

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(sum_added = rowSums(pick(ends_with('_added')), 
     na.rm = TRUE) * condition) %>%
   mutate(across(c(ends_with('_added'),-sum_added), ~ .x * !condition))
```

-output

```
df1
 idc transaction_id r1 r1_added r2 r2_added r3 r3_added condition sum_added
1   1             17 84       66 50       31 20       68         0         0
2   2             95 28        0 58        0 91        0         1       148
3   3             27 18       56 52       28 61       99         0         0
4   4             16 51        0 90        0 87        0         1       145
5   5              8 98       74 97        9 11       49         0         0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(idc = 1:5, transaction_id = c(17L, 95L, 27L, 16L, 
8L), r1 = c(84L, 28L, 18L, 51L, 98L), r1_added = c(66L, 15L, 
56L, 22L, 74L), r2 = c(50L, 58L, 52L, 90L, 97L), r2_added = c(31L, 
95L, 28L, 80L, 9L), r3 = c(20L, 91L, 61L, 87L, 11L), r3_added = c(68L, 
38L, 99L, 43L, 49L), condition = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: and how do this too, i need r1_added =0 , r2_added=0,,, and so on,updating values in rows with condition 1.

Comment: @hfa does the update works for you

Comment: Thanks that works perfect! i don't understand how it works (~.x *!condition)  but i will figure out

Comment: @hfa If `v1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)` `!v1` changes the 1 to FALSE and 0 to TRUE which is basically 0 and 1